# Is there any benefit to honoring all the graves in Solomon's Boneyard?

Tags: ios, solomons-boneyard

I know there's an achievement for honoring all the graves (standing still for a second, therefore placing flowers) in the level, but is there any gameplay benefit to doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [forum post](http://raptisoft.com/forum/index.php?topic=278.msg1515#msg1515) asking for a bonus for honoring all the graves, it looks like there's currently no benefit.