# Does Mourning the Dead Serve Any Practical Purpose?

Tags: solomons-boneyard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any benefit to honoring all the graves in Solomon's Boneyard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8092/is-there-any-benefit-to-honoring-all-the-graves-in-solomons-boneyard)

In [Solomon's Boneyard](http://toucharcade.com/2010/09/08/solomons-boneyard-review-endless-survival-prequel-to-solomons-keep/), if you pause your wizard/witch over a tombstone for a short moment, you place a small bouquet of flowers at the grave, and a name (presumably that written on the stone) is displayed at the top of the screen.  Is there any practical purpose for this feature?

---

[image: Solomon's Boneyard]

Comment: So... is this a duplicate of [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8092/is-there-any-benefit-to-honoring-all-the-graves-in-solomons-boneyard)? They're not exact, but I'm not sure that it makes a difference. Your call, or maybe sjohnston's.

Comment: @Grace > Actually... it looks like pretty much an EXACT duplicate (But mine has a picture!).

Comment: Sounds good to me, then. Closed by autorial request. ♪ You have probably read it, but for other readers, **the answer is no, there is no purpose**.